# Is it safe to run python -m http.server XXXX

Tags: java, html, server, command-prompt, firewall

I am trying to run a html project that I have started. I need to do so on a local server to reach full capabilities for the java aspect. I've been told that "python -m http.server 8000" is a good way of going however is this safe and will my information on my computer be compromised or is this 100% local? I only ask because my Firewall didn't like the idea of me running this server.

Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default the HTTP server binds to all interfaces which opens it up to the World thus the firewall complains. If you use it only from localhost, use `--bind` parameter to only bind to localhost.

Full command:
`python -m http.server 8000 --bind 127.0.0.1`

Source: https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html

Note: `--bind` was introduced in Python 3.4, so you need 3.4 or newer to use `--bind`.

Comment: thank you tiblu, if i may ask out of curiousity where does 127.0.0.1 come from or is this some sort of universal localhost number?

Comment: Good question! IPv4 standard just reserved the 127.0.0.1/8 for loopback, but I don't know why 127.0.0.1 and not something else. Maybe some Google and Wiki will bring some light - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost. Let us know if you followed through.

Comment: Haven't found the answer but thought this was interesting:

Comment: While we all know and love 127.0.0.1 as the localhost, it’s worth noting that it won’t be the localhost forever. 127.0.0.1 is how the localhost is designated in IPv4 communications and, as IPv6 slowly takes over, it will be designated by a much more intuitive number: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1.